# Racket error - module: identifier already required

Tags: racket

Am getting the following error when trying to run (require 2htdp/image) in DrRacket:

```
module: identifier already required
```

The error occurs after updating from DrRacket 7.3 to 7.4.

I uninstalled all previous versions of DrRacket including 7.4 and reinstalled 7.3. Am continuing to get error.

I went through some of the solutions in stackoverflow for this error message before posting. However, my code is simple. I cannot even run (require 2htdp/image) on its own without code without triggering the error.

[edit]

**Check-syntax:**

```
unsaved-editor:2:9: module: identifier already required in: rectangle
```

I have no idea what that means, since there is no rectangle attached to this test.

[edit]

```
Language: Beginning Student [custom]; memory limit: 128 MB.
Teachpack: world.rkt.
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you remove the `(require )` line and try using `2htdp/image` functionality?

Comment: running 2htdp/image without require triggers this error: 2htdp/image: this variable is not defined

Comment: I think that what @MyStackRunnethOver meant is that, what will happen if you use `rectangle` without `require`-ing anything? In any case, the unbound identifier error indicates that you are using a student language. What specific language is that (beginning vs intermediate vs advanced)? What are teachpacks that you are using?

Comment: @Sorawee The "rectangle" message I refer to in my edit is not using a rectangle. The error is simply from hitting run after adding (require...). To answer your question, images trigger "this function is not defined" without the (require...). Please see my edit.

Answer (score 4):

it's means you added teachpack (*.rkt) has same function name "rectangle".
just clear teachpacks only add you really needed teachpacks

(require 2htdp/image) "image.rkt" have function rectangle.

(require htdp/world) "world.rkt" also have function rectangle.

In same folder create a.rkt b.rkt c.rkt

create file a.rkt

```
#lang racket
(provide t)
(define (t x) (+ x 1))
```

create file b.rkt

```
#lang racket
(provide t)
(define (t x) (+ x 2))
```

create file c.rkt

```
#lang racket
(require (file "a.rkt"))
(require (file "b.rkt"))
(t 3)
```

run c.rkt will shows

```
module: identifier already required in: t
```

Comment: thanks. It seems the update to 7.4 changed the defaults to load world teachpack. Strange that reinstalling 7.3 didn't revert to previous settings.